# Please explain the algebraic reasoning in this textbook

Tags: medications

I am reading Dennis M. Brown “Drug Delivery Systems in Cancer”.  On [Page 29](https://books.google.com/books?id=u4BHBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT57&lpg=PT57&dq=increasing%20exposure%20time,%20i.e.%20AUC50%20%3D%20k&source=bl&ots=SNt0nehJvC&sig=ACfU3U3ixSl9lv47yzzccZsATC2DAg6BSQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-sp30jpvkAhUCvVkKHetAATcQ6AEwCnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=increasing%20exposure%20time%2C%20i.e.%20AUC50%20%3D%20k&f=false) when referring to monotonic increase or decrease of n (being the number of cells n(t) I believe) then how are they getting

AUC<sub>50</sub> = T<sup>(1-1/n)</sup>

I get how it equal k<sup>(1/n)</sup> because we just raise each side of equation IC<sub>50</sub><sup>n</sup> * T = k to the 1/n power but not getting the the double equality here.

The relationship between IC<sub>50</sub> and AUC<sub>50</sub> occurs when n = 1 in (IC<sub>50</sub>)<sup>n</sup> * T = k which reduces to AUC<sub>50</sub> = k, meaning effect only depends on AUC.

[image: screenshot of book]

Comment: what is the relationship between AUC and IC?

Comment: When n=1 $ (IC_{50})^{n}T = k reduces to  (AUC_{50}) = k $ meaning effect only depends on AUC.  Not sure why the latex is not working here.

Comment: latex doesn't work in comments, you can edit the question with this info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take the general equation they mentioned, (IC<sub>50</sub>)<sup>n</sup>T = k, and rearrange it to IC<sub>50</sub> = (k/T)<sup>1/n</sup> = k<sup>1/n</sup>T<sup>-1/n</sup>. (IC<sub>50</sub>)<sup>n</sup>T = k reducing to AUC<sub>50</sub> = k if n=1 implies that AUC<sub>50</sub> = IC<sub>50</sub>T if n=1. If this equation holds for other n, then AUC<sub>50</sub> = k<sup>1/n</sup>T<sup>1-1/n</sup>. That looks a LOT like the text if the author accidentally inserted a =.

This next bit is more speculative because the exact descriptions of these terms in the source are not available online, but AUC generally stands for "area under curve," aka integration. I have doubts AUC<sub>50</sub> is some definite integral of IC<sub>50</sub> because when n=1, IC<sub>50</sub> = k/T, which has an indefinite integral F(T) = k*ln(T) + constant.

Comment: Yes they must have inserted another = by accident!  Thanks so much!